# Control over OpenAPI 3.0 package generation for jersey-jaxrs

Tags: openapi-generator

I'm using [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) for `jersey-jaxrs` (OpenAPI 3.0). I'd like to control the package where my code is being generated.

I'm setting the `api-package`, `model-package`, `package-name`, and `invoker-package` options, all to a `xxx.yyy.zzz` value.

My problem is that most of the code is generated under `gen.xxx.yyy.zzz`, and it's not discoverable by the part of the code generated under `xxx.yyy.zzz`. **Implicitly, `gen` is prepended to the package name**. I understand this is convenient in many cases, but not mine. Is there any generator option to avoid this?

I've learned a bit about the Mustache templates and they seem like a possible solution, but maybe a bit too much for my requirements.

Ultimately, I can move the code in `gen` to the other (non-gen) package manually, and it works, but this is quite inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by altering the `configOptions` and overriding the `sourceFolder` option like so

```
    openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("jaxrs-jersey")
    inputSpec.set("$projectDir/schema.yml")
    outputDir.set("$projectDir")
    configOptions.set([
            sourceFolder: "src/main/java" // This is "src/gen/java" by default
     ])
    }
```

All configuration options for the Open Api generated `jersey-jaxrs` server can be found [here](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/jaxrs-jersey.md)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out that you can mark folders in IntelliJ IDEA as *"generated sources root"*, which makes it discoverable to the rest of the project's code.

This doesn't solve my question, but it does solve the problem that originated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the jaxrs-spec openapi-generator for maven.

It turned out that the **sourceFolder** prop was placed in

```xml
 <configuration>
```

scope , and not in the

```xml
 <configOptions>
```

scope.

---

After i moved it there and set it to:

```xml
<configuration>
  <!--Common configuration-->
  <configOptions>
    <!-- jaxrs-spec specific options -->
    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
  </configOptions>
</configuration>
```

Everything worked :-)